# Question regarding llply or lapply - applying functions to data.frames in a list

Tags: list, r, plyr, zoo, lapply

Dear R user community,

I have many data.frames in a list, as follows (only one data.frame in the list of 21 shown for convenience):

```
> str(datal)
List of 21
 $ BallitoRaw.DAT                :'data.frame': 1083 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ Filename: Factor w/ 21 levels "BallitoRaw.DAT",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ date    :Class 'Date'  num [1:1083] 7318 7319 7320 7321 7322 ...
  ..$ temp    : num [1:1083] NA 25.8 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 24.4 ...
```

If I work on each data.frame in the list individually I can create a zoo object from temp and date, as such:

```
> BallitoRaw.zoo <- zoo(datal$BallitoRaw.DAT$temp, datal$BallitoRaw.DAT$date)
```

The zoo object looks like this:

```
> head(BallitoRaw.zoo)
1990-01-14 1990-01-15 1990-01-16 1990-01-17 1990-01-18 1990-01-19 
        NA       25.8         NA         NA         NA         NA
```

How do I use llply or apply (or similar) to work on the whole list at once?

The output needs to go into a new list of data.frames, or a series of independent data.frames (each one named as in the zoo example above). Note that the date column, although a regular time series (days), contains missing dates (in addition to NAs for temps of existing dates); the missing dates will be filled by the zoo function. The output data.frame with the zoo object will thus be longer than the original one.

Help kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
makeNamedZoo <- function(dfrm){ dfrmname <- deparse(substitute(dfrm))
  zooname <-dfrmname
   assign(zooname,   zoo(dfrm$temp, dfrm$date))
   return(get(zooname)) }
ListOfZoos <- lapply(dflist, makeNamedZoo)
names(ListOfZoos) <- paste( sub("DAT$", "", names(dflist) ), "zoo", sep="")
```

Here is a simple test case:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a= letters[1:10], date=as.Date("2011-01-01")+0:9, temp=rnorm(10) )
df2 <- data.frame(a= letters[1:10], date=as.Date("2011-01-01")+0:9, temp=rnorm(10) )
dflist <- list(dfone.DAT=df1,dftwo.DAT=df2)
ListOfZoos <- lapply(dflist, makeNamedZoo) 
names(ListOfZoos) <- paste( sub("DAT$", "", names(dflist) ), "zoo", sep="")

$dfone.zoo
2011-01-01 2011-01-02 2011-01-03 2011-01-04 2011-01-05 2011-01-06 2011-01-07 
 0.7869056  1.6523928 -1.1131432  1.2261783  1.1843587  0.2673762 -0.4159968 
2011-01-08 2011-01-09 2011-01-10 
-1.2686391 -0.4135859 -1.4916291 

$dftwo.zoo
2011-01-01 2011-01-02 2011-01-03 2011-01-04 2011-01-05 2011-01-06 2011-01-07 
 0.7356612 -0.1263861 -1.6901240 -0.6441732 -1.4675871  2.3006544  1.0263354 
2011-01-08 2011-01-09 2011-01-10 
-0.8577544  0.6079986  0.6625564
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an easier way to achieve what I needed:

```
tozoo <- function(x) zoo(x$temp, x$date) 
data1.zoo <- do.call(merge, lapply(split(data1, data1$Filename), tozoo))
```

The result is a nice zoo object.